# Using sqlite in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, sqlite

I'm trying to create db in sqlite and then store data dynamically into some table, again I want to fetch multiple data which should be stored in json file and finally from json array this data will be presented in GUI. I tried following way, but there's some error, I need help.

**index.html**

```
<body ng-app="starter" ng-init="statusMessage='started';fname='bikash';lname='dan'">
    <ion-pane>
        <ion-header-bar class="bar-stable">
            <h1 class="title">Ionic Blank Starter</h1>
        </ion-header-bar>
        <ion-content ng-controller="ExampleController">
            <input type="text" ng-model="fname" placeholder="Your first name" /><br />
            <input type="text" ng-model="lname" placeholder="Your first name" />

            <button class="button" ng-click="insert('{{fname}}','{{lname}}')">Insert</button>
            <button class="button" ng-click="select('{{lastname}}')">Select</button>
            <p> {{statusMessage}} </p>
            <p>{{fname}} {{lname}}</p>

            <div ng-repeat="d in all_data">
               <p>{{p.fname}} <br/> {{p.lname}}</p> 
            </div>
        </ion-content>
    </ion-pane>
</body>
```

**app.js**

```
var db = null;
var example = angular.module('starter', ['ionic', 'ngCordova'])
    .run(function ($ionicPlatform, $cordovaSQLite) {
        $ionicPlatform.ready(function () {
            if (window.cordova && window.cordova.plugins.Keyboard) {
                cordova.plugins.Keyboard.hideKeyboardAccessoryBar(true);
            }
            if (window.StatusBar) {
                StatusBar.styleDefault();
            }
            db = $cordovaSQLite.openDB("my.db");
            $cordovaSQLite.execute(db, "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS people (id integer primary key, firstname text, lastname text)");
        });
    });

example.controller("ExampleController", function ($scope, $cordovaSQLite) {

    //var items = [];
    $scope.insert = function (firstname, lastname) {
        $scope.statusMessage = "Start Inserting: " + $scope.fname +' '+ $scope.lname;
        var query = "INSERT INTO people (firstname, lastname) VALUES (?,?)";
        $cordovaSQLite.execute(db, query, [$scope.fname, $scope.lname]).then(function (res) {
            $scope.statusMessage += "INSERT ID -> " + res.insertId;
        }, function (err) {
            $scope.statusMessage = err;
        });
    }

    $scope.select = function (lastname) {
        $scope.statusMessage = "Start Fetching";
        var query = "SELECT firstname, lastname FROM people WHERE lastname = ?";
        $cordovaSQLite.execute(db, query, [$scope.lname]).then(function (res) {
            if (res.rows.length > 0) {
                var data=[];

                for (var i = 0 ; i <= res.rows.length; i++) {
                   var obj={fname:res.rows.item(i).firstname , lname:res.rows.item(i).lastname};
                   data.push(obj);
                   //console.log("Result->"+ res.rows.item(i).firstname + " " + res.rows.item(i).lastname);
                   //$scope.statusMessage = "SELECTED -> " + res.rows.item(i).firstname + " " + res.rows.item(i).lastname;
                  }
                };
                $scope.all_data =data;

            } else {
                $scope.statusMessage = "No results found";
            }
        }, function (err) {
            console.error(err);
        });
    }

});
```

Comment: I ve just found something beneficial for you .Have look at this (http://jaydata.org/blog/angularjs-with-jaydata%E2%80%93-the-todo-example-with-the-itemstore-api) .

Comment: @katmanco Its very different from my way, anyway thats cool one. I need help in this if theres any error on mine code.

Comment: @New Dev, attracting your attention, This is my another problem Im struggeling with. Need help. 
-With Regard